# Django model - hours calculator

Tags: python, django, model

Good evening !
I have a question. I can not find over the internet how to solve my problem. I want to have database row in which i can put hours - not datetime or time but for example 01:34 ( 1 hour 34 minutes). I don't know how to deal with it can someone help ?

Regards

Comment: Is this a `TextField` in your models?

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to store minutes or seconds in an integer field, and then format the total minutes on output or render.

An example template tag for the display of seconds into minutes:seconds

```
@register.filter
def custom_time_format(seconds_total):     
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds_total, 60)
    return f"{minutes}:{seconds}"
```

template code example, assuming the tags file is called custom_time_tags.py

```
{% load custom_time_tags %}

{{ time_stored_as_int|custom_time_format }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate further about the limitation you want to overcome?
Why datetime doesn't suite your need for example?

Without any other information I would say that you could consider a TextField with a specific format constraint (ie. H:M) for the input and you could save the value as an integer (intended as hours and minutes converted to minutes only).

If this comes from a user input, it is a good practice to perform validation on the model form or on the model (raising ValidationError on failure).

For example, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/), you should be able to do something like that

```
class CustomTimeField(models.IntegerField):
  description = "A field to save time (str) H:M as tot minutes (int) in db, but act like a str"

  def get_db_prep_value(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
    if value is None:
      return None
    h, m = value.split(":")
    return int(h * 60 + m)

  def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None or isinstance(value, int):
      return value
    try:
      return f"{value//60}:{value%60}"
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
      raise ValidationError("This value must be a string or an int.")

  def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
    return self.to_python(value)

  def formfield(self, **kwargs):
    from django.forms import TextField
    defaults = {'form_class': TextField}
    defaults.update(kwargs)
    return super(CustomTimeField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

Comment: there's no limitation it should act like a hours logbook and then i could sum it up